# Customizing OData DateTime output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have the following model:

```
public class PersonModel {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDay {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

When a make a get request OData returns a DateTimeOffset instead of a DateTime. For instance, the request '/api/rest/people/1' returns:

```
{
 id:1,
 birthDay: "12/7/2016 8:57:58 PM +00:00"
 ....
}
```

What I want? I just need to return the Date value "12/7/2016". I have tried to implement a custom ODataPayloadValue converter but OData doesn't seem to understand the 'DateTime' type.

```
 public override object ConvertToPayloadValue(object value, IEdmTypeReference edmTypeReference)
    {
        /// There isn't a IEdmtypeRefere.IsDateTime 
        /// Thus OData always think that DateTime is equals to DateTimeOffset
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            ///Do some stuff here.
        }

        return base.ConvertToPayloadValue(value, edmTypeReference);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that there is a way to achieve what I want by implementing two classes:

```
 // A custom serializer provider to inject the AnnotatingEntitySerializer.
public class CustomODataSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    private AnnotatingEntitySerializer _annotatingEntitySerializer;

    public CustomODataSerializerProvider()
    {
        _annotatingEntitySerializer = new AnnotatingEntitySerializer(this);
    }

    public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.IsEntity())
        {
            return _annotatingEntitySerializer;
        }

        return base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }
}


// A custom entity serializer that adds the score annotation to document entries.
public class AnnotatingEntitySerializer : ODataEntityTypeSerializer
{
    public AnnotatingEntitySerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        : base(serializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override ODataEntry CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)
    {
        ODataEntry entry = base.CreateEntry(selectExpandNode, entityInstanceContext);

        PersonModel person = entityInstanceContext.EntityInstance as PersonModel;
        var property = entry.Properties.Where(x => x.Name == "birthDate").FirstOrDefault();
        property.Value = ((DateTimeOffset)property.Value).DateTime.ToShortDateString();


        return entry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way - extend your model like this:

```
public class PersonModel {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDay {get;set;}
    // add this property and you get it. You can rename it if you want
    public string BirthDate {get {return this.BirthDay.ToShourtDateString(); }}
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I implement like this, I will have two properties in my Model, one string and the other will be a DateTime, furthermore, the consumer of the API might think that he/she can set values for the 'string BirthDate'. I was thinking something like a output filter...